# Materialize Grid Columns overflowing

Tags: html, css, grid, materialize

I'm trying to make a "products" page, I have a card in each column, and only one row.

```html
    <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <h4 class="grey-text text-darken-4">
                            New Listings
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                        <div class="card hoverable">
                            <a href="">
                                <div class="card-image">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x250/?mobile" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-content">
                                    <h6 class="truncate black-text"><b>Lorem</b></h6>
                                    <p class="truncate grey-text text-darken-2">Buy Lorem</p>
                                    <p class="right-align grey-text"><small>Today</small></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                        <div class="card hoverable">
                            <a href="">
                                <div class="card-image">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x250/?mobile" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-content">
                                    <h6 class="truncate black-text"><b>Lorem</b></h6>
                                    <p class="truncate grey-text text-darken-2">Buy Lorem</p>
                                    <p class="right-align grey-text"><small>Today</small></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6 m4 l3">
                        <div class="card hoverable">
                            <a href="">
                                <div class="card-image">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x250/?mobile" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-content">
                                    <h6 class="truncate black-text"><b>Lorem</b></h6>
                                    <p class="truncate grey-text text-darken-2">Buy Lorem</p>
                                    <p class="right-align grey-text"><small>Today</small></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

My code looks something like this, a card jumps from one line to the next even though there is space for it, I don't really know what is wrong

Edit: It is working now, gave a class "small" to card div. Thanks to Sean.

Comment: That link doesn’t work, but I suspect the issue is your cards are different heights. Rows don’t handle it well. You have 3 solutions: add a size to the card to fix the height (small, medium, large), use JS to automatically make all cards be the height of the tallest card, or output opening and closing row divs every nth card - this last option is not really suitable when you have multiple breakpoints like yours though. If you can’t fix using the first option I can share the JS fix.

Comment: @SeanDoherty Thank you, giving the card a size of small fixed it.

Comment: Also, updated the link.

Comment: Great. Just be careful your content is always visible through all your breakpoints, sometimes restricting the height can cut it off.

Comment: Yes I will deal that from Image Manipulation either with CSS or JS @SeanDoherty

Comment: Great. I've added an answer so that anyone coming here via search can find the solution quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Materialize rows don't handle cards with different heights very well, for this scenario, it helps to fix the height of your cards to make them uniform using the three provided classes:|

```
<div class="card small">
   <!-- Card Content -->
</div>
```

Three sizes applied as an extra class on the card - `small`, `medium` and `large` which equate to:

```
.card.small {
    height: 300px;
}

.card.medium {
    height: 400px;
}

.card.large {
    height: 500px;
}
```

https://materializecss.com/cards.html#sizes